# std::lock_guard within openmp parallel

Tags: c++, locking, openmp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mutex l;

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<24;i++){
        int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(l);
        cout<<"i: "<<i<<" thread_num:"<<thread_num<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I can't understand the output of such code. Looks like that mutex is not unlocked after each loop. But lock_guard is defined inside loop, isn't it?

```
i: 0 thread_num:0
i: 1 thread_num:0
i: 2 thread_num:0
i: 3 thread_num:0
i: 4 thread_num:0
i: 5 thread_num:0
i: 12 thread_num:2
i: 13 thread_num:2
i: 14 thread_num:2
i: 15 thread_num:2
i: 16 thread_num:2
i: 17 thread_num:2
i: 6 thread_num:1
i: 7 thread_num:1
i: 8 thread_num:1
i: 9 thread_num:1
i: 10 thread_num:1
i: 11 thread_num:1
i: 18 thread_num:3
i: 19 thread_num:3
i: 20 thread_num:3
i: 21 thread_num:3
i: 22 thread_num:3
i: 23 thread_num:3
```

My system is linux with g++ 9.1.0

Comment: What exactly confuses you about the output?

Comment: @MikevanDyke I expected the 4 threads print alternately.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that, because you will never know which thread gets be scheduled on the CPU and what thread acquires the lock next. The only thing you can guarantee is that, only one thread will `cout` at a time. If you want to bring order into the execution, you will need further synchronization methods, for example a condition variable

Comment: @MikevanDyke I know what you mean. But the result looks like thread0 get the lock continuously for 6 times.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a possible and also likely outcome, because when a thread is blocked on the lock, it needs to be woken up, which does not happen instantly. During the time, the blocked thread is woken up, the thread that was holding the lock, only has to execute a few instructions until it holds the lock again. For example, put in a sleep before acquiring the lock and the threads will more likely alternate

Comment: Resonable. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend. You can find documentation of `std::lock_guard` at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard

If you read it it explains how this works.

Comment: From my output, thread0 first got the lock, then case "i=0" finished and lock is unlocked. And then there are 4 threads wanting to hold the lock, why thread0 has highest priority to get the lock?

Comment: "Why does thread0 have highest priority to get the lock?" As @MikevanDyke said: it doesn't. Which thread gets the lock is entirely arbitrary and unspecified.